# How to display a list of all object types in Salesforce instance

Tags: apex, visualforce, schema

I am trying to get a VisualForce page to display a SelectList of every object type in a Salesforce instance. Account, Contact, etc. I am using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`but am running into an issue where I am getting the error "System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: Schema.DescribeSObjectResult."

Here is my code. I am particularly puzzled because, without the commented out line, I am not actually using the Schema.DescribeSObjectResult object, only the SObjectType.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class searchController {

    //Properties
    public SelectOption[] objectSelect{
        get; set;
    }

    public String objName{get; set;}

    //Constructor
    public searchController()
    {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

        objectSelect = new SelectOption[]{};
        for(String name : schemaMap.keySet())
        {
            //objectSelect.add(new SelectOption(name, schemaMap.get(name).getDescribe().getLabel()));
            objectSelect.add(new SelectOption(name, name));
        }

        objName = objectSelect[0].getValue();
        filter = new FilterRule(objName);
    }


}
```

And my VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page controller="searchController">

<apex:form id="searchForm">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="objSelectBlock" title="What are you Searching For?">
            <apex:selectList value="{!objName}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectSelect}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize describes. You will have to call describeGlobal at least once per transaction every time you need to use it.

Comment: So there happens an implicit serialization in the constructor? This is puzzling a bit since LucidLunatic writes the result of Schema.getGlobalDescribe() only to a local variable...

Comment: Actually, we are missing code. I suspect the culprit is the FilterRule class. This code is obviously pared down, because, as you've observed, there's nothing here that would cause the error. Also, see how the OP assigns a value to "filter", which has no definition. This code wouldn't compile as is.

Comment: @sfdcfox is correct about the code being pared down- my apologies for the error that would prevent it from compiling. Though I have yet to pinpoint the original cause of the error, I have gotten it to work. Thank you for our help.